# Angular validation FormControl start input class as ngvalid but it's still unused

Tags: html, angular, typescript, validation

After start FormControl to my form, they marked in green with `ng-valid` but didn't use it yet.
When writing text and clear the input it's go `ng-invalid` as needed and when the input is OK the `ng-valid` is back as needed.

**How to start the fields without `ng-valid` ?** No need any class in this input until it dirty.

Here is my html: (you can see validate need to work only after using one of the fields)

```
<form [formGroup]="mainForm">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="customerID">ID</label>
              <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              id="customerId"
              formControlName="customerId"
              (click)="validate()"
              placeholder="e.g 123456789">
              <span class="error invalid-feedback" *ngIf="customerIdInvalid">ID is important, numbers only!</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
              <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              id="firstName"
              name="firstName"
              formControlName="firstName"
              (click)="validate()"
              placeholder="First Name">
            <span class="error invalid-feedback" *ngIf="firstName?.invalid">First name invalid, try again</span>
            </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Here is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'new-customer',
  templateUrl: './new-customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-customer.component.scss']
})
export class NewCustomerComponent implements OnInit {
  mainForm = new FormGroup({
    customerId: new FormControl(),
    firstName: new FormControl()
  });

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  get customerIdInvalid(){
    return this.mainForm.get('customerId')?.invalid;
  }

  get firstName(){
    return this.mainForm.get('firstName')
  }

  validate(){
    this.mainForm.get('customerId')?.setValidators([Validators.required , Validators.pattern(/^-?([0-9]\d*)?$/) , Validators.minLength(6)]);
    this.mainForm.get('firstName')?.setValidators([Validators.required , Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z]+$') , Validators.minLength(2)]);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I change my component to:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'new-customer',
  templateUrl: './new-customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-customer.component.scss']
})
export class NewCustomerComponent implements OnInit {

  mainForm = new FormGroup({
    customerId: new FormControl('',[Validators.required , Validators.pattern(/^-?([0-9]\d*)?$/) , Validators.minLength(6)]),
    firstName: new FormControl('',[Validators.required , Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z]+$') , Validators.minLength(2)])
  });

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  get customerId(){
    return this.mainForm.get('customerId');
  }

  get firstName(){
    return this.mainForm.get('firstName')
  }



  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.mainForm.valid);
    if(this.mainForm.valid){
      console.log(this.mainForm.value);


    }
  }
}
```

So now all my css with `.ng-invalid` changed to `.ng-dirty.ng-invalid`
In that way I will assure only inputs that used will be mark red.